# Virtualbox DHCP Server

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Currently my network is using the subnet 255.255.248.0 or /21.
My DHCP Server is listing in the range 3.1-3.254.

Everytime I create a virtualbox the client get an IP from the DHCP Server, after I enable the network bridge in virtualbox.

Is it possible to enable a kind of a virtual dhcp server, so the virtual machiene get automatically an IP from another range in my subnet, which looks in the router like a static IP, without set the ip of every virtual machine to static?
It should be possible to communicate with the VM from every network device, so NAT isn't a choice.

Comment: Have you considered using a bridged mode LAN adaptor so that it gets DHCP from your main physical router?

Comment: Yes, but I want to use a different IP-range for all VMs like 4.1-4.254

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/398478/change-virtualbox-dhcp-to-issue-192-168-x-x-adresses-instead-of-10-0-x-x-dress

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for.

Open up Virtual box then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>  then Click on Network

[image]

Then add a new NAT network. then edit the network. by clicking on the screwdriver icon.

[image]

Type in your network range or leave as default then click <kbd>ok</kbd>

[image]

Then go to your VM Settings --> Network and change `attached to`: `NAT NetWork`. then pick the name of the NAT network you created

[image]

I booted into a DVD Live install of Xubuntu 15.10 on my VM as you can see I got an IP address from the NAT Network I created in Virtual Box. and I can ping out. But you will need to add a DNS server manually if you want resolve host names.

[image]

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Looks good, but I think its not possible to connect to this device from a computer in the local network

Comment: Have you tried it.